# Is there a way to remove/rename the Chrome "Other Bookmarks"?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

The Chrome "Other Bookmarks" folder on Bookmark Bar is ugly-named and consumes too much screen space. Is there a way to [remove it](http://www.google.com.hk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+remove+chrome+%22other+Bookmarks%22)?

Comment: Further reason this is important, other than ugliness: When the window is very thin (i.e. when it is at 50% screen width) all the other bookmarks are truncated, so you only see the leftmost ones, but for some reason the "Other Bookmarks" folder shows in full! This might mean several important buttons are hidden just for a truly useless one! Removing it's contents 100% worthwhile if you use multiple windows at half width!

Comment: Please update the accepted answer to Slackliner's one, that simply works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove it, not yet. Use <kbd>ctrl + shift + b</kbd> to show / hide the toolbar if you think it is ugly and don't want to see it.

You can then hide it and opt to use a bookmark extension, like '[Bookmarks Menu](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi?hl=en)'.

Comment: Please update this comment because it's marked as correct but it really misses the point. Slackliner below explains that manually deleting all the contents of "Other Bookmarks" will cause it to disappear from the bookmarks menu, which is 100% what I needed (I don't mind seeing it in Bookmarks Manager, the problem is it showing 100% of the time)

Answer (score 12):

If you empty it, it disappears. I just dumped everything into a folder named Other and dropped it on the end of my Bookmarks Bar folder

Comment: This does hide the `Other Bookmarks` folder from the bookmarks bar, but doesn't remove it altogether.

Comment: 100% solved my problem, thanks Slackliner. That the folder is still visible in Bookmarks Manager doesn't bother me at all Paul, I just don't want it showing constantly.

Answer (score 0):

If the term "*Other bookmarks*" gives you the creeps, and don't mind a small hack, you could just modify the text in the locale database.

We want to modify the `locales/en-US.pak` file (of course, it will be a different one if you're not using the English US locale).

Before anything, do a **backup** of the .pak file you intend to modify.
Then close Chrome (and ensure no *chrome* process remains in memory).

Using Ubuntu, it's in the `/...install-dir.../google/chrome/locales/` dir.

Modify the file using a **binary** editor (Linux: used *okteta*), an editor that only modifies the bytes at a given location (no concept of line, ... ; the file size is not changed).

Then from
[image]

To
[image]

Be careful not to modify anything outside of the "Other bookmarks" text

- There is no `\0` delimitor: the lengths of the terms have probably been saved somewhere in the pak file (I wouldn't mess with that)
- Complete with spaces if the new term is shorter than the original one
- Obviously the new term cannot be longer than the original one...

Save the modified file. Open Chrome.

You should see

[image]

---

NB

You could also run a command like

```
 sed -i 's/Other bookmarks/Oops!          /' en-US.pak
```

that does the change.

In `s/X/Y/`, `X` and `Y` must have the same length...

---

Disclaimers

- at your own risk. It's a *pak* file in locales, and we only overwrite some text without affecting the size or coding, so it should not matter. But who knows...
- the *pak* file might/will probably be replaced during the next Chrome update...